# How to sync 2 folders every day?

Tags: 13.10, sync

I am moving a Firefox profile folder on my SSD disk to fully utilize SSD's speed. However to prevent accidental formatting of this folder, I also want to have a daily sync with another folder on internal hard disk which I never format.

How can I do this? Am I forced to use `rsync` with `cron` or there is a tool which can do all this automatically? I have never used rsync or cron before.

Comment: Rsync and cron are the right tools. I am sorry you feel that way about them, 'forced' sounds a bit negative to me. You can also try backup software like deja-dup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who have writing `cron` and `rsync` command, I recommend this app: http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/

It has a GUI and creating a repetitive cron job is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1):

I use rsync over ssh with chron to keep an up-to-date copy of my entire /home over the internet every couple of hours. It takes seconds and works flawlessly. If you take an hour to figure it out, you'll never have to think about it again.

To make it a little easier to manage, you can create a fill called `firefox-settings-backup.sh` somewhere with the rsync command line, and use `Scheduled tasks` from the repos as a simple cron management tool to run `firefox-settings-backup.sh`